# Java: Get month Integer from Date

Tags: java, date, calendar

How do I get the month as an integer from a Date object (`java.util.Date`)?

Comment: actually getMonth() on Date is deprecated since forever ;)

Comment: @slhck: Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH).

Comment: @adarshr That's why I didn't write an answer. So much for a specific and well-researched question!

Comment: @Zenzen I don't see the problem in using a deprecated method in a mostly deprecated class.

Comment: @Muhd if you are working with dates, help yourself and use [joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) or any other library.

Comment: @slhck I like using Stack Overflow as a reference, and this was missing so I asked.

Comment: @Serabe: the problem is that there are better solutions (ones that at least aren't deprecated). And getMonth has been deprecated for like 14 years now and it's been deprecated for a reason.

Comment: @Zenzen: it was a joke regarding the use of a class whose methods are mostly deprecated (22 out of 33, including constructors). Sorry for the misunderstood.

Comment: Seriously, when this question was asked 11 years ago there often was no way around using `Date`, but today no one should. We have [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Answer (score 87, accepted):

## java.time (Java 8)

You can also use the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 and convert your [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object to a [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) object and then just use the [`getMonthValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getMonthValue--) method.

```
Date date = new Date();
LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
```

Note that month values are here given from 1 to 12 contrary to `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)` in adarshr's answer which gives values from 0 to 11.

But as Basil Bourque said in the comments, the preferred way is to get a [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum object with the [`LocalDate::getMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getMonth--) method.

Comment: Good answer. Note to the reader: You may want to specify a time zone rather than rely on the call for default shown in the Answer. A new day (and month) dawns earlier in Paris, for example, than Montréal. If you care specifically about Montréal, the use `ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )`.

Comment: I just want to add that there is a great article about the introduction of *java.time* api http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: By the way, another note to the reader: You can also get a **[`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum object** rather than a mere integer number. `Month m = localDate.gotMonth();` See [`LocalDate::getMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getMonth--) method. Using objects such as this makes your code self-documenting, ensures type-safety, and guarantees valid values. See [Enum tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) by Oracle.

Comment: if you use `date.toInstant()` and you happen to be working with a `java.sql.Date` (the child of `java.util.Date`) then you will get an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Try `new java.sql.Date(src.getTime()).toLocalDate()`

Comment: @Adam Much easier to convert to/from [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) by using the new conversion methods added to that old class. `java.sql.Date.valueOf( myLocalDate )` and `myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate()`  Also, JDBC drivers updated for JDBC 4.2 or later no longer need `java.sql` types, and can directly address `java.time` types via the `ResultSet::getObject` and `PreparedStatement::setObject` methods.

Comment: Good to know about JDBC 4.2 and I agree with you, but the warning about the `UnsupportedOperationException` applies unless you are absolutely sure you're not going to be passed `java.sql.Date` when you use `java.util.Date::toInstant`. A poor implementation when they wrote `java.sql.Date`, IMHO.

Answer (score 332):

```
java.util.Date date = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Comment: Note that `Calendar.MONTH` is for no apparent reasons ZERO based, ie January==0. Now that's documented just fine in the API, but it's still confusing as hell for first time users. I've yet to find anyone who could tell me why they went with that - maybe time for a new SO question myself (though I fear there isn't any great background to that :/ )

Comment: @Voo Date.getMonth() method was zero based, which is probably the main reason Calendar.MONTH is as well.

Comment: @Muhd Sure after all it was the replacement. But that only shifts the question around to why was Date.getMonth() zero based? Imo a horrible design, especially since days start at one (they could at least be consistent!). I assume it was just some oversight in a not especially well designed API (both Date and Calendar) to begin with. But maybe there's some precedent - it just seems strange to me and has caused problems to more than one beginner in my experience.

Comment: Actually it's been asked already here on SO (and not only). The bottom line is tnat it's a result of badly designed API. I mean as you mentioned the whole Date class is a joke. Fun fact is that not only Java suffers from this problem - iirc JavaScript's Date getMonth() also starts with a 0!

Comment: @Voo `getYear()` is also, "for no apparent reasons", subtracted by 1900.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Turns out JS's Date [is just a clone of Java's](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2010/10/every-day-i-learn-something-new-and-stupid/#comment-1048)

Comment: **CAUTION** This Answer fails to address the issue of time zone. For date-time values around the end of the month, the resulting month number could swing either way to past month or next month depending on the JVM’s current default time zone. Better to explicitly specify the desired/expected time zone.

Comment: Best answer for lower api (In my case api 21)

Comment: For some reason this returns 7 for september here. Doesn't make sense. If I take a look at the calendar object start date is set for february. Doesn't make sense, no matter how I look at it.

Answer (score 21):

If you use **Java 8** date api, you can directly get it in one line!

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
int month = today.getMonthValue();
```

Comment: is this 0 for january or 1?

Comment: This only returns single-digit values i.e. you can't form a mm dd value from it without using date or calendar

Answer (score 9):

## Joda-Time

Alternatively, with the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class.

```
//convert date to datetime
DateTime datetime = new DateTime(date);
int month = Integer.parseInt(datetime.toString("MM"))
```

…or…

```
int month = dateTime.getMonthOfYear();
```

Comment: Even simpler, just ask the `DateTime` object’s for its month. `int month = dateTime.getMonthOfYear();`

Comment: Good call Basil, I have updated the code. However, I like the `.toString("MM")` as it shows there are more possibilities than just "MM".

Comment: This answer ignores the crucial issue of time zone. See my comments on Question and sibling Answer. I suggest passing a `DateTimeZone` object to that DateTime constructor: `DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" )`.

Answer (score 8):

## tl;dr

```
myUtilDate.toInstant()                          // Convert from legacy class to modern. `Instant` is a point on the timeline in UTC.
          .atZone(                              // Adjust from UTC to a particular time zone to determine date. Renders a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
              ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )   // Better to specify desired/expected zone explicitly than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.
          )                                     // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
          .getMonthValue()                      // Extract a month number. Returns a `int` number.
```

## `java.time` Details

[The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30847992/642706) by Ortomala Lokni for using [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) is correct. And you *should* be using java.time as it is a gigantic improvement over the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. See the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) on java.time.

I'll add some code showing how to use java.time without regard to java.util.Date, for when you are starting out with fresh code.

Using java.time in a nutshell… An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in UTC. Apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

The [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) class is a sophisticated [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to represent a month in general. That enum has handy methods such as getting a localized name. And rest assured that the month number in java.time is a sane one, 1-12, not the zero-based nonsense (0-11) found in java.util.Date/.Calendar.

To get the current date-time, [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is crucial. At any moment the date is *not* the same around the world. Therefore the month is not the same around the world if near the ending/beginning of the month.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );  // Or 'ZoneOffset.UTC'.
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
Month month = now.getMonth(); 
int monthNumber = month.getValue(); // Answer to the Question.
String monthName = month.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

If you can't use Joda time and you still live in the dark world :) ( Java 5 or lower ) you can enjoy this :

Note: Make sure your date is allready made by the format : dd/MM/YYYY

```
/**
Make an int Month from a date
*/
public static int getMonthInt(Date date) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    return Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(date));
}

/**
Make an int Year from a date
*/
public static int getYearInt(Date date) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    return Integer.parseInt(dateFormat.format(date));
}
```

Comment: You are the mother! / Είσαι η μάνα!

Answer (score 1):

If we use java.time.LocalDate api, we can get month number in integer in single line:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
...
int currentMonthNumber = LocalDate.now().getMonthValue(); //OR
LocalDate scoringDate = LocalDate.parse("2022-07-01").getMonthValue(); //for String date
```

For example today's date is 29-July-2022, output will be 7.

Comment: May also use `YearMonth.now()` or `MonthDay.now()`. And may pass a `ZoneId` to the `now` method to make it clear that the operation is time zone dependent.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date mDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
mDate.getMonth() + 1
```

The returned value starts from 0, so you should add one to the result.

Comment: 2 problems with your answer: one is that you can make a date with current time by doing `new Date()` without `System.currentTimeMillis`. The other is that getMonth is deprecated.

Comment: @Muhd So what is the best solution?

Comment: @Muhd The System.currentTimeMillis() I added here was to indicate that here is a long type, and you can specific the date.

Comment: Date::getMonth was already deprecated in Java 1.1 (http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/java/jdk1.1-beta2-docs/api/java.util.Date.html#getMonth%28%29)

Comment: Deprecated in Java 12