# How to get current month, previous month and two months ago

Tags: java

I need a function that will return three strings:

1. first string will contain the current month and the current year.
2. second string will contain the previous month and current year.
3. third string will contain two months ago and current year.

This, of course, should also work if current month is January, for example.

So right now, the results should be:

- September 2015
- August 2015
- July 2015

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing that worked like I need it to work.

Comment: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: What Java version are you using? Java SE 8?

Comment: Why did you add the "webdriver" tag? How is this question related?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Java 8 version (using the [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class) is [here](http://ideone.com/4LqrrP).

```
YearMonth thisMonth    = YearMonth.now();
YearMonth lastMonth    = thisMonth.minusMonths(1);
YearMonth twoMonthsAgo = thisMonth.minusMonths(2);

DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM yyyy");

System.out.printf("Today: %s\n", thisMonth.format(monthYearFormatter));
System.out.printf("Last Month: %s\n", lastMonth.format(monthYearFormatter));
System.out.printf("Two Months Ago: %s\n", twoMonthsAgo.format(monthYearFormatter));
```

This prints the following:

> Today: September 2015
>
> Last Month: August 2015
>
> Two Months Ago: July 2015

Comment: Consider to use YearMonth instead of LocalDate.

Comment: @Puce Thanks. I have updated the answer to use that class for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 10):

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(new Date());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM YYYY");
System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));   // NOW
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));   // One month ago
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));   // Two month ago
```

Comment: Plus one but one small thing you will need four M's to generate the complete months name: SimpleDateFormat("MMMM YYYY")

Comment: MMM will display Sep, Aug, Jul ... perhaps it will be better to use MMMM to display full month names

Comment: @Daniel Yes correct, I corrected my answer. Thank you for the correction of the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using `LocalDate` written in Kotlin.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.TextStyle
import java.util.Locale

val currentMonth = LocalDate.now().month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault()) //February
val prevMonth = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault()) //January
val twoMonthsAgo = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(2) //DECEMBER
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Get the Months you need (Current, Current -1 and Current -2)  see
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182996/java-get-month-integer-from-date)
2. Get the Textual form of the Months like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038570/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-to-localized-month-name-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public static void main(String[] args) {


Date currentDate = null;
String dateString = null;
try {
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // anything 0 - 23
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);//previous month
    //c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -2);//two months back
    currentDate = c.getTime(); // the midnight, that's the first second
    // of the day.


    SimpleDateFormat sdfr = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");
    dateString = sdfr.format(currentDate);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(dateString); //prints current date
```

}

Comment: after removing comment it will print -1 month date and -2 month date