# How to add list elements of certain range to arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of Calendars/dates? I have to extract the month's dates from that list and add to new list? How can i do this in java?

use case: list1 contains dates from 20 jan to april 20. I have to separate the dates as jan 20-feb19, feb20-march19, march20-april20. How can i do this in java?

Comment: Did you try anything? Provide some code

Comment: Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182996/java-get-month-integer-from-date

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework question, where the op did not try anything.

Comment: use case: list1 contains dates from 20 jan to april 20. I have to separate the dates as jan 20-feb19, feb20-march19, march20-april20. How can i do this in java?

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect use of a for loop

Here is some sudo-code for what you would need to do:

```
List<Calendar> dates...
List<Integer> months...
for (Calendar calendar : dates){
    months.add(calendar.getMonth());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an ArrayList in JAVA, you can only add an element at the end of the list and not in the middle of this list by example.

Comment: use case: list1 contains dates from 20 jan to april 20. I have to separate the dates as jan 20-feb19, feb20-march19, march20-april20. How can i do this in java?

Comment: you can use the function split()